# Converting this date format 2021-04-26 05:31:38 to 26 Apr, 2021 in magento 2

Tags: php, date, format

How can we Convert this date format `2021-04-26 05:31:38` to `26 Apr, 2021` in Magento 2. Please let me know how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for some time and checking in few date-time format related sites I got the answer myself that worked for me.

```
 $date = $_order->getCreatedAt();//2021-04-26 05:31:38   (input)
  $date_year=substr($date,0,4);
  $date_month=substr($date,5,2);
  $date_day=substr($date,8,2);
$date_month_name=date("M", mktime(0,0,0,$date_month,$date_day,$date_year));
echo $date_day." ".$date_month_name.", ".$date_year;//26 Apr, 2021  (output)
```